# How to make PhpStorm autocomplete props from a node_modules library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, phpstorm, webstorm, blueprintjs

In my React project I've installed [blueprintjs](https://blueprintjs.com/) as a dependency.

When I do this in code:

```
import {Popover} from "@blueprintjs/core";

...

render() {
        ...
        <Popover /* No autocomplete for props */>
        </Popover>
```

I don't get any autocomplete for PropTypes of Popover component.

Note: the Popover component is written in TypeScript.

How can I get autocomplete to work in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is tracked at [WEB-38214](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38214), please follow it for updates